# Android Sqllite :Unable to solve syntax error in query

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm updating cart at every tab,in the code I'm updating cart item but showing error in syntax.

```
 ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    DbHelper dbHelper = new DbHelper(context);

    SQLiteDatabase database;
    database=  dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    values.put(DbConstants.COLUMN_MEMBER, cartItemBean.getCOLUMN_MEMBER());
    values.put(DbConstants.COLUMN_DATE, cartItemBean.getCOLUMN_DATE());
    values.put(DbConstants.COLUMN_TIME, cartItemBean.getCOLUMN_TIME());

    String sql2 = "UPDATE " + DbConstants.TABLE_CART + " SET " +
            DbConstants.COLUMN_MEMBER + " = '" + cartItemBean.getCOLUMN_MEMBER() + "' AND "
            + DbConstants.COLUMN_DATE + " = '" + cartItemBean.getCOLUMN_DATE() + "' AND "
            + DbConstants.COLUMN_TIME + " = '" + cartItemBean.getCOLUMN_TIME() + "' AND "
            + DbConstants.COLUMN_TOTAL_PRICE + " = '" + cartItemBean.getCOLUMN_TOTAL_PRICE() + "' AND "
            + "' WHERE " +
            DbConstants.COLUMN_PACKID + " = '" + cartItemBean.getCOLUMN_PACKID() + "' AND "
            + DbConstants.COLUMN_USERID + " = '" + cartItemBean.getCOLUMN_USERID() + "'";

     database.execSQL(sql2);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were adding `AND` instead of the `comma`, removing that will solve the problem.

Change the query to:

```
String sql2 = "UPDATE " + DbConstants.TABLE_CART + " SET " +
        DbConstants.COLUMN_MEMBER + " = '" + cartItemBean.getCOLUMN_MEMBER() + "', "
        + DbConstants.COLUMN_DATE + " = '" + cartItemBean.getCOLUMN_DATE() + "', "
        + DbConstants.COLUMN_TIME + " = '" + cartItemBean.getCOLUMN_TIME() + "', "
        + DbConstants.COLUMN_TOTAL_PRICE + " = '" + cartItemBean.getCOLUMN_TOTAL_PRICE() + "' "
        + " WHERE " +
        DbConstants.COLUMN_PACKID + " = '" + cartItemBean.getCOLUMN_PACKID() + "' AND "
        + DbConstants.COLUMN_USERID + " = '" + cartItemBean.getCOLUMN_USERID() + "'";
```

Check the sample in this [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_update_query.htm).

Comment: above I'm updating cart but now i want to delete one item from cart on the  basis of package id  @ArulKumar

Comment: Can you check on the tutorial for [Delete](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_delete_query.htm)

Comment: I'm using this query but it does not working @ArulKumar                                            DbHelper dbHelper = new DbHelper(context);
        SQLiteDatabase database;
        database=  dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        database.delete(DbConstants.TABLE_CART, DbConstants.COLUMN_PACKID + "=? AND "
                 + DbConstants.COLUMN_USERID + "=?" , new String[]{packId,userId});
        database.close();

Comment: I'm not able to find the answer from the query you posted. Can you please post a separate question for this and some one can answer that.